# How to prevent Azure to add %3F in the SAS url?

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-storage

I have a SAS token that looks like

```
?sv=2017-04-17&ss=b&srt=o&sp=rw&se=2017-11-13T21:36:10Z&st=2017-10-13T13:36:10Z&spr=https&sig=abcd
```

The problem is that I have already "**?**" in the SAS token but azure service is returning the url like this

```
var sasUrl = blobService.getUrl(container, file.name, sas);
```

URL:

```
https://container.blob.core.windows.net/demo/The%20Fall%20%5B1%20Minute%20Short%20Film%5D.mp4?%3Fsv=2017-04-17&ss=b&srt=o&sp=rw&se=2017-11-13T21%3A36%3A10Z&st=2017-10-13T13%3A36%3A10Z&spr=https&sig=abcd
```

What i want is to remove "**%3F**" from the SAS url, how can i do that.

Comment: you can use [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: I have tried is not working.

Comment: can you show the code how you tried

Comment: I tried this way

var x = sasUrl.replace('%3F', ''");

Comment: it working fine just run the code snippet below and check console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming because different SDKs generate SAS token differently. If you use .Net SDK, it prepends `?` in the token however if you use Node SDK, it does not prepend this character. Since Node SDK does not prepend this character, when a blob url is created by the SDK, it simply URL encodes this SAS Token value (that's why it converts `?` to `%3F`) and adds the value as query string parameter.

To fix this issue, you can check if the 1st character in SAS Token is a `?` character. If it is there, then you can just create a substring from this by removing the first character. You can do something like:

```
var sasToken = "?sv=2017-04-17&ss=b&srt=o&sp=rw&se=2017-11-13T21:36:10Z&st=2017-10-13T13:36:10Z&spr=https&sig=abcd"
if (sasToken.charAt(0) === "?") {
    sasToken = sasToken.substr(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var url ="https://container.blob.core.windows.net/demo/The%20Fall%20%5B1%20Minute%20Short%20Film%5D.mp4?%3Fsv=2017-04-17&ss=b&srt=o&sp=rw&se=2017-11-13T21%3A36%3A10Z&st=2017-10-13T13%3A36%3A10Z&spr=https&sig=abcd";

console.log(url.replace('%3F',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously i was trying

```
sasUrl = sasUrl.replace('%3F', '');
```

Now I tried

```
sasUrl = sasUrl.replace('?%3F', '?');
```

it worked for me.